# How to flash custom ROM on Samsung Galaxy A22 4G?

Tags: samsung, rom-flashing, custom-roms

I have the Samsung Galaxy A22 4G (SM-a225m) and want to custom ROM it, but how? I am hating One UI and really want to change to a custom ROM.

I know how to install custom recoveries like TWRP, but I don't really know the custom ROM installation. If someone could help me do it and send me the link to the file and how to install it. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Have you tried the following guide? [How to Install Custom ROM on Samsung Galaxy A22 SM-A225F](https://www.getdroidtips.com/custom-rom-samsung-a22-sm-a225f/)

Comment: Actually, I did but I ended reflashing stock rom again because of it, I mean i would prefer someone with a custom rom on the a225m to tell me how to do it